# dojo for content from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

The case:
I use dojo to request a page and load it into a div ( view ).

The problem:
The content that gets loaded into a form contains a dojo form and relevant objects, textbox, etc... how can I controller these widgets? I believe the current way I am working around the issue is sloppy and could be more refined.

Comments are in the code to help explain the issue I have. Please let me know your thoughts.

```
function (parser, domAttr, util, ready, dom, on, request, domStyle, registry, TextBox) {
//This prepares the doc main html page We are looking for a click of a menu option to load in thats pages pages content     

        ready(function () {     
            //Look for click of menu option            
            on(dom.byId('steps'), "a:click", function(e) {
                event.preventDefault();

                //Get the div we are going to load the page into
                var view = domAttr.get(this, "data-view");                
                // function that loads the page contents
                load_page(view);  
            });
        });    

        function load_page(view) {
            //First I see if this page already has widgets and destroy them
            //We do this so users can toggle between menu items
            // If we do not we get id already registered
            var widgets = dojo.query("[widgetId]", dom.byId('apply-view')).map(dijit.byNode);
            dojo.forEach(widgets, function(w){ 
                w.destroyRecursive();
            });


            //get the html page we are going to user for the menu item
            request.post("/apply_steps/"+view, {
                data: {
                    id: 2
                }
            }).then(
            function(response){
                //Add the content and parse the page   
                var parentNode = dom.byId('apply-view');
                parentNode.innerHTML = response;
                parser.parse(parentNode);

                //This is where it is sloppy
                //What I would prefer is to load a new js file the controlls the content that was just loaded
                //What happens now is I create a traffic director to tell the code what main function to use
                controller_director(view);
            },
            function(error){
                util.myAlert(0, 'Page not found', 'system-alert');
            });
        }   

        function controller_director(view) {
            //based on the view switch the function
            switch(view) {
                case 'screening_questions':
                    screening_questions();
                    break;
            }

        }  

        function screening_questions() {
            //Now we are controlling the page and its widgets
           // How would I get this info into a seperate js file that i would load along with the ajax call??
            ready(function () {         

                on(dom.byId('loginForm'), "submit", function(e) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formLogin = registry.byId('loginForm');
                    authenticate();                   
                });
            }); 

            this.authenticate = function() {
                var formLogin = registry.byId('loginForm');
                if (formLogin.validate()) return;
            } 
        }    
});
```

Comment: I suggest you just make your form a custom templated widget, and write your event handlers and form validation logic in your form widget. In this case, all you have to do is ajax in your page with the declarative reference `<div data-dojo-type="my/form"></div>` and call the dojo parser. https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/_TemplatedMixin.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will give it a go.